# How do you actually install Apache airflow

Tags: python

I'm trying to install apache airflow to use in python.

The Airflow website [mentions](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/local.html) installing it using pip by running the commands in the picture...
But *where* do I run these? Do I open up a command line window and put them in one by one? put it all in a .py file and run it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These commands indeeed have to be run on the command line on your computer. Looking at the commands provided you should probably use a unix shell such as bash as I'm not sure the Windows command prompt will work with some of the commands (e.g. exporting and setting variables).